# ArcMap grids with different coordinate systems problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I'm doing an exercice in cartography. We should do the canvas to a topographic map (1:25000), we start with a given point, we make the other 15, into an Excel file, (map is 7'30" * 7'30") the goal is to make two grids :

First : Graticule grid, graticule and labels (interval is 2'30"), geographical coordinate system

Second : Measured grid, tick marks and labels, projected coordinate system

The problem is when I want to do the first grid, it doesn't show as intended due to the data frame's coordinate system being the projected one, and if I change to the geographical one the shape of the map changes to a square instead of a rectangle. The second grid I don't have a problem with.

Comment: You're doing the correct thing. The graticule might look odd but it's showing where the lat-lon lines are in the pcs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you do not have a problem with your second grid then I think you should delete that part of your question.  Then, coming back to your first grid, I think you should try to ask a question (punctuated with a question mark) whenever you want an answer.